# Asymmetrical errorbar with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot asymmetrical errorbars with pandas. According to [official docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/visualization.html#plotting-with-error-bars) this should work

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0.2,0.7]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df[0].plot.bar(yerr=[df[1], df[2]], ax=ax)
```

But pandas renders errorbar as `df[1]` for both lower and upper limits (-0.2/+0.2 istead of -0.2/+0.7):

[image]

Where do I make a mistake?

I use pandas v0.20.3 with python v2.7.13 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `yerr` is 1D:

```
yerr=[df[1], df[2]]
```

It needs to be 2D, specifically one row per data point and each row having two values for negative and positive error:

```
yerr=[[df[1], df[2]]]
```

Comment: actually either 1D or 2D seems to output the correct result in a newer version of pandas, I tested with pandas 1.2.4 and matplotlib 3.3.4